# End of String After a space-dash-space

Tags: regex

I have tried many times to figure out the regex for getting the end of the string after the second dash in my string, but none of them are working properly.  My strings come in the following form:

```
Special - VIP - 40
2-Hr and 1-Hr - 2-Hour Workshop - 35
```

I need to extract the numbers at the end of the strings.  I was able to use `(?:[^-\n]+-){2}(.*)$` for the first string, but I couldn't apply it to the second string (since the numbers actually come after the 4th dash).  I tried to put  before and after the dash in the expression but that did not work.

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the pattern `one-or-more-digits` then `end-of-string`? If so, how about just doing:

- [`\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/AFRtHL/1)

[image]

Anyways, that should get you started, if for example, you only want a number with two digits, change `\d+` to `\d\d`. And if it needs to be after two dashes, well that's a bit trickier, but let's start with the above first. If you really needed the second though it might start looking something like this (though it really only makes sense if the pattern is much more complex than the examples given):

- [`(?: - )(?:[^-]+|(?:\S-.)|(?:.-\S))+(?: - )(\d+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZvPXH5/1)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might use:

```
^(?:[^-\n]+-){2}.*\b(\d+)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:[^-\n]+-){2}` Match 2 dashes
- `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `\b` A word boundary
- `(\d+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fZN6YQ/1).

Comment: Cool answer -- much better technique than mine. By the way, how does `(?:[^-\n]+-){2}` or rather (for clarity) `([^-\n]+-){2}` work? `not-dash` followed by dash -- and then I assume it just ignores whether there is a space after the dash? On a side note I wonder if a dash is ever used like a semi-colon where there might be a dash after, I suppose maybe stilted dialogue ("H- h- how could you?"), but that's it. Maybe this whole comment was a digression, but nice solution!

Comment: Here would be an example of what I mean btw: https://regex101.com/r/qvXs8V/1